# Webapp hangs during startup; when removing Class.forName(driverClass), it continues

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I am trying to connect to database to retrieve some data and put it in primefaces table. Here is my code:

```
public Connection initConnection() {

    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        if (connection == null) {

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
            System.out.println("Connected.");

        } else if (connection.isClosed()) {

            connection = null;
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
            System.out.println("Connected.");

        }

    } catch (SQLException sqlException) {

        sqlException.printStackTrace();

    } finally {

        return connection;
    }

} // End getConnection.

public void setIngredients() throws SQLException {

    getIngredients = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM ingredient");
    rset = getIngredients.executeQuery();

    while(rset.next()) {
        ingredients.add(new Ingredients(rset.getString(2), rset.getString(3), rset.getString(4), rset.getString(5), rset.getDouble(6)));
    }

    dbc.closeConnection();
}

public List<Ingredients> getIngredients() throws SQLException {

    return ingredients;

}

       <div id="content">
            <p:dataTable var="ingredient" value="#{newIngredientBean.ingredients}">
                <p:column headerText="Ingredient Name">
                    <h:outputText value="#{ingredient.ingredientName}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Ingredient Short Name">
                    <h:outputText value="#{ingredient.ingredientShortName}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Batch Code">
                    <h:outputText value="#{ingredient.supplierBatchCode}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Expiry Date">
                    <h:outputText value="#{ingredient.ingredientExpiryDate}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Quantity">
                    <h:outputText value="#{ingredient.ingredientQuantity}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </div>
```

Now when I launch the project all I see is "waiting for localhost" if I remove this line "Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");" the webpage loads but throws MySQL no driver error. I am able to retrieve data within main method in Java but then I try to fill the table it never loads.. Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Did you read the server log? Big chance that you'll see a rather self-explaining `ClassNotFoundException` in there.

Comment: The only event in the log is this "Warning:   The web application [/SafaFood] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered."

Comment: After "waiting for localhost" this is what I get: "com.google.common.collect.ComputationException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This web container has not yet been started"

Comment: Oh, you're using GAE?

Comment: Nope, I'm using JSF and Primefaces as far as I know..

Comment: I was talking about the server. Is it Google App Engine?

Comment: Server I am using is GlassFish 4.

Comment: Okay. How exactly are you sure that it's the loading of the driver which is blocking the webapp's startup? Isn't it actually the obtaining of the connection? Did you run the debugger?

Comment: When I remove the "Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");" line it runs but throws no SQL driver found exception. When I do add it I get web container is no initialized or something like that. When I run within Java using main method I have no problems retrieving data from SQL.

Comment: I know. I was asking, is the startup blocking at the line `Class.forName()` or at the line `DriverManager.getConnection()`? Does the code execution advance beyond `Class.forName()` line? Are you familiar with debuggers? If not, then throw in some poor man's `System.out.println()` lines printing the current state of interest so that you can read in server log which code exactly has executed and which not.

Comment: It goes past Class.forName() so the problem must be the Primefaces datatable.

Comment: Does it also go past `DriverManager.getConnection()`? And `setIngredients()`? And `connection.prepareStatement()`? And `getIngredients.executeQuery()`? And .. And .. Please find the blocking method using a debugger!

Comment: It goes past everything successfully, I think its the primefaces datatable which is causing the issue at this stage.

Comment: Okay. Thus `setIngredients()` is definitely called? Who exaclty called it? You in a `@PostConstruct`? And `getIngredients()` is thus also successfully called? And, you said that the webpage never loads. Can you please clarify this once again in developer's terms instead of enduser's terms? Does the browser's progress indicator forever run? Or does it indeed stop, but all you get is a blank page? Have you looked at retrieved HTML output, HTTP traffic monitor and JS console?

Answer (score -1):

Do you have the mysql connector jar? In case if you do not you can get it from [here](https://code.google.com/p/find-ur-pal/downloads/detail?name=mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar&).Download it and include it in your java build path.